# GIT New Repo Error

Tags: git, github, version-control

Making a new branch on github throwing this error

> remote: Repository not found.
>   fatal: repository 'https://github.com/mckenzieflavius/myrepository.git/' not found

Ive checked spelling a thousand times so ill give exact information on what im doing.

**What I've Done**

on github im on an account with a different email address. e.g. mckenzie@hotmail.com and made a new repository.

locally my config email address is mckenzie@hotmail.co.uk but ive set it manually for this 1 repository to mckenzie@hotmail.com along with my username to that of my git account.

Locally ive ran `git init` followed by `git commit -m "initial commit"`

and `git remote add origin https://github.com/myrepository.git` to set it

then git push origin master

But i get the above error. Im really not sure what im doing wrong.

Ive even followed the guide on git to push an existing project to git and i get the same thing.

EDIT:

I know it was only helpful but ive already put that ive created a repo on github earlier on in this question, an image here

[image]

Comment: when I follow the link you provided I get 404 error. Is your repo private?

Comment: @CoosPot its a private repo

Comment: Are you authenticating with your git client? If not then it will be told the repository doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, exactly which git command is giving the error posted at the top of the question? If you've managed to create the repository on github, then clearly it isn't github that is giving that error message, or are you saying that you're trying to create a new branch *on github*, and github is showing that error message? If so then you've found a bug and should post it to them.

Comment: Im trying to PUSH to github so when i run the `git push origin master` command

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Im not aware of how to authenticate from git client, im using the command line.

Besides ive just been following exactly what git sais to do i had no idea it would be done any different for private repos

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius You can clone the private repo to local first. If you can successful cloned, then you should push succeed.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your Github user-account https://github.com/mckenzieflavius?tab=repositories, you have not created a repository yet. You will only be able to push to remote repos that actually exist, so what you have to do is create `myrepository` first via the Github website, then you can push to it.

Comment: Depends. Maybe his repository is private.

Comment: My repo is private

Answer (score 0):

This is probably caused because your repo is set to private and you don't have rights to push to this repository.

Answer (score 0):

Right so i found this pretty strange and im not sure which of the following it had to do with but ill list all the changes I've done anyway

As i said before i was using a different account from the one that hosted the private repository, i added the second account as a collaborator. Im not sure this is what fixed it however.

Secondly the local repository wasn't empty, it had files on, previously i committed the files via `git commit -m "Initial file commit"` but i didn't add them, (I was following the instructions on the git page, but i didn't want a readme on the page). So when i then went to commit it was throwing that error.

**Solution**

I think the problem was that there was nothing committed, but the information that the GitHub error thrown was inaccurate and misleading. By nothing committed i mean there was no file changes in the commit it was just an empty folder, i think there needs to be at least 1 file or folder in the local repo before you can push it.

Also when i googled that error, a load of unrelated ones came up and i was following them in hopes mine would also work, but they didn't.